# PDO Exception, Duplicate Entry . While I try to re-index my data in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, pdo

I am trying to re-index my data in magento. All indexes are working ok except for the "Product Attributes", whose current status is stuck on "processing". When I try to index using magento admin panel, it shows the below error.

[image: Magento Admin Panel error. Error]

and when I try to re-index my data through the shell using the command " php indexer.php --reindexall ", it throws the following exception

```
    Product Attributes index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint vio                                                                                        lation: 1062 Duplicate entry '163-137-1-74' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /home/emperorh                                                                                        ome/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Inte                                                                                        grity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '163-137-1-74' for key 'PRIMARY                                                                                        '' in /home/emperorhome/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully
```

I am unable to locate where the real problem is. I don't know where is making a duplicate entry, as I am new to magento. ANy Help will Be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Please reformat this error message to make it fit the screen

Answer (score 0):

It must error in `product's 163 attribute 137(attribute id.`).Just unset of of that attribute (137 attribute id)of that product and then  save the product(Product id 163).After that Indexing product attribute.